# Unable to Connect - http://10.0.2.2/test.php Local Host XAMPP

Tags: xampp, localhost

I have made a program *using PHP Script*, but whenever i am trying to run my script *using Browser* getting Problem Loading Page:**Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 10.0.2.2.**

I have saved test.php under - *E:\xampp\htdocs*

**test.php:**

```
     <?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("registration_login");

$_POST["sUsername"] = "testname";
$_POST["sPassword"] = "testpassword";
$_POST["sName"] = "testname";
$_POST["sEmail"] = "testemail";
$_POST["sTel"] = "testtel";


$strUsername = $_POST["sUsername"];
$strPassword = $_POST["sPassword"];
$strName = $_POST["sName"];
$strEmail = $_POST["sEmail"];
$strTel = $_POST["sTel"];

/*** Check Username Exists ***/
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE Username = '".$strUsername."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if($objResult)
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "0";
$arr['Error'] = "Username Exists!";
echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
}

/*** Check Email Exists ***/
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE Email = '".$strEmail."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if($objResult)
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "0";
$arr['Error'] = "Email Exists!";   
echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
}

/*** Insert ***/
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO member (Username,Password,Name,Email,Tel)
VALUES (
'".$strUsername."',
'".$strPassword."',
'".$strName."',
'".$strEmail."',
'".$strTel."'
)
";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if(!$objQuery)
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "0";
$arr['Error'] = "Cannot save data!";   
}
else
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "1";
$arr['Error'] = "";
}

mysql_close($objConnect);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to *use your machine's IP Address* in place of 10.0.2.2

So **complete URL** should look like this:

```
    http://ipaddress/test.php
```

**Note:** Above solution for while you want to *use Local Server via Android Emulator*

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where the 10.0.2.2 is coming from? By default localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1. This could potentially be your problem.

The problem you are experiencing wouldn't be from your PHP script. But rather the request isn't getting from your browser to your Apache web server. 
- You'll want to ensure Apache is running. 
- You could try making sure you are using localhost in the URL. 
- You could check the apache log files under /Xampp/apache/logs/ and see if there is any recent errors being logged. 
- You could also try a tool like Fiddler to see the exact response of the request.

Hope that helps.